# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 2055: Cursor is not connected

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

this is code, it works fine for first time and when i try again it show error.

```
def order():
    order_options = {1: "Serial_no",2: "Name_of_wildlife",3: "State",4: "No_of_species",5: "Total_area",6: "Total_population"}

    a = input("\nEnter Favourable Arrangement Order(asc or desc) : ")
    if a not in ["asc", "desc"]:
        return order()

    print("\n========================Chose value to Order By========================")
    for i in range(1, 7):
        print(f"\n{i}) Order by {order_options[i]}")

    Ord = int(input("\nENTER YOUR CHOICE IN NUMBER(1 TO 6) : "))
    if Ord not in range(1, 7):
        print("Please enter Correct Option.")
        return order()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM RECORD ORDER BY {order_options[Ord]} {a}")
    rec = cur.fetchall()
    headers = ['Serial_no', 'Name_of_wildlife', 'State', 'No_of_species', 'Total_area', 'Total_population']
    print(tabulate.tabulate(rec, headers=headers, tablefmt="grid"))
    cur.close()
```

Cursor problem I think.

Comment: The problem is with how you're setting `cur`, which isn't shown here.

Comment: If you reuse the cursor in multiple calls to the function, you shouldn't use `cur.close()` at the end of the function.

Comment: You're calling `cur.close()` at the end of the function, so of course the cursor is already closed if you call the function a second time.